# Load external image in Haskell Diagrams

Tags: haskell, external, haskell-diagrams

So I have this doubt. I already have code that works with local (embedded) image files, but now I need to load an external image instead. Dumb replacing with `loadImageExt` didn't help:

```
productImageIO :: IO (Diagram B)
productImageIO = do
  res <- loadImageExt "https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/dkscdn/16JDNMJRDNCLPSBLKJRD_Black_Black_White_is/"
  return $
    case res of
      Left err -> mempty
      Right product -> image product



• No instance for (Renderable (DImage Double External) B)
        arising from a use of ‘image’
    • In the expression: image product
      In a case alternative: Right product -> image product
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘case res of
           Left err -> mempty
           Right product -> image product’
   |
26 |       Right product -> image product
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking at the source of [loadImageExt](https://docs.futurice.com/haskell-mega-repo/diagrams-lib-1.4.1.2/src/Diagrams.TwoD.Image.html#loadImageExt) and [readImage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.9.5/docs/src/Codec-Picture.html#readImage) I cannot see where it actually performs http stuff to get the image.

And the docs say, *loadImageExt, Check that a file exists, and use JuicyPixels to figure out the right size, but save a reference to the image instead of the raster data*

So please excuse my ignorance, but does this mean that I need to add http loading logic in this case? Or I'm just missing some point to make this work?

**UPD**: I might be wrong and there's some fast and easy way to load external images by just putting the link, but what worked for me was using [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html), getting the response in ByteString and parsing it:

```
productImageIO :: String -> IO (Diagram B)
productImageIO path = do
   response <- fmap getResponseBody $ parseRequest path >>= httpBS
   return $
     case loadImageEmbBS response of
        Left error -> mempty
        Right decodedImage -> image decodedImage
```

It could load even https image, like this https://sneakernews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/jordan-russell-westbrook-signature-shoe-creamsicle-3.jpg?w=1140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`loadImageExt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.2.3/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Image.html#v:loadImageExt) appears to expect a `FilePath`, not a URL, but that's not what the compiler is complaining about. It is complaining that the particular image returned, a `DImage Double External`, is not [`Renderable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Types.html#t:Renderable). This could be because the [renderer](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#rendering-backends) in use doesn't understand external images; for instance, [`Diagrams.Backend.SVG`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-svg-1.4.2/docs/Diagrams-Backend-SVG.html#t:SVG) appears to support `Embedded` but not `External`. In contrast, [`Diagrams.Backend.Html5`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-html5-1.4.1/docs/Diagrams-Backend-Html5.html#t:Html5) supports `External` but not `Embedded`. At a guess, it's expected that your diagram refers using local filenames to images, not cross-site URLs. It could be that you can inject URLs with [`uncheckedImageRef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4.2.3/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Image.html#v:uncheckedImageRef), but still only if the backend supports `External`. The [Diagrams manual section on images](https://archives.haskell.org/projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#images) claims only the Cairo backend does, but that could be inaccurate.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks a lot! I'll try to finish the task with Cairo and update the post.